# Cannot knit rmarkdown to PDF when a simple table is present

Tags: r, r-markdown, pdflatex

I wrote an rmd file in RStudio and cannot seem to get a PDF to knit if any tables are in the body of the text.  I tried making a super simple test rmd to verify that the table was the one causing the error.

```
---
title: "test"
output: pdf_document
---

| Right | Left | Default | Center | 
|------:|:-----|---------|:------:| 
| 12 | 12 | 12 | 12 | 
| 123 | 123 | 123 | 123 | 
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
```

Here is the error I get when I try to knit.

> Output created: test.pdf Error in
>   tools::file_path_as_absolute(output_file) :    file 'test.pdf' does
>   not exist Calls:  ->  In addition: Warning
>   messages: 1: running command '"pdflatex" -halt-on-error
>   -interaction=batchmode "test.tex"' had status 1  2: In readLines(logfile) : incomplete final line found on 'test.log'
>   Execution halted

Here is my session info:

> R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
>   LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United
>   States.1252 [4] LC_NUMERIC=C
>   LC_TIME=English_United States.1252
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages: [1] rmarkdown_1.9   magrittr_1.5
>   flextable_0.4.3 knitr_1.20
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] Rcpp_0.12.16
>   digest_0.6.15     rprojroot_1.3-2   R.methodsS3_1.7.1 R6_2.2.2
>   backports_1.1.2   evaluate_0.10.1   zip_1.0.0          [9]
>   gdtools_0.1.7     stringi_1.1.7     uuid_0.1-2        R.oo_1.21.0
>   R.utils_2.6.0     xml2_1.2.0        tools_3.4.4       stringr_1.3.0
>   [17] officer_0.2.2     yaml_2.1.18       compiler_3.4.4
>   base64enc_0.1-3   htmltools_0.3.6

Answer (score 4):

Try my new absolute favorite thing, `flextable` - it renders to HTML and PDF without the pain of knitting using other methods:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(flextable)
library(magrittr)
row1 <- c(12,12,12,12)
row2 <- c(123,123,123,123)
row3 <- c(1,1,1,1)
df <- as.data.frame(rbind(row1,row2,row3))
names(df) <- c("Right","Left","Default","Center")
df %>% regulartable() %>% autofit()
```
````

It produces this in both HTML and PDF:

[image: flex3]

Comment: I tried copying that exact code chunk into a test rmd file and got an error when I tried to knit into a PDF:
Quitting from lines 7-16 (test.Rmd) 
Error in knit_print.flextable(x, ...) : 
 unsupported format for flextable rendering:latex
Calls: <Anonymous> ... fun -> withVisible -> knit_print -> knit_print.flextable
Execution halted

Comment: is your pandoc version > 2?

Comment: also, have you installed pandoc? Lots of document rendering requires it, and it's installed outside of RStudio

Comment: Omg thank you.  After updating pandoc (I was 1.17.2), my original issue just magically disappeared.

Comment: Yay! So happy to hear that. The same thing happened to me a couple months ago and I pulled my hair out for almost 3 days before reinstalling the right version of pandoc :)